# Jettpack Compose Dialog Orientation Flicker

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a Jetpack Compose project where I got an issue in Dialog Composable when orientation changed. I have a screen with LazyColumn with some items, and on clicking it, I open the Dialog. I have this added to my screen

```
val openDialog = rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}
val selectedVideoId = rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
YoutubeDialog(openDialog = openDialog, videoId = selectedVideoId.value)
```

and on click i change the value of openDialog

**This is my dialog composable function**

```
@Composable
fun YoutubeDialog(openDialog: MutableState<Boolean>, videoId: String){
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<YoutubeViewModel>()
if (openDialog.value){
    Dialog(
        properties = DialogProperties(
            usePlatformDefaultWidth = false,
            dismissOnBackPress = true
        ),
        onDismissRequest = {
            openDialog.value = false
            viewModel.youtubePlayer.value?.release()
            viewModel.onClear()
        }
    ) {
        if (openDialog.value){
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Black)
            ){
                //Some code here for close button

                YoutubePlayer(id = videoId, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
            }
        }
    }
}else
    LockScreenOrientation(orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
}

@Composable
fun YoutubePlayer(id: String, modifier: Modifier){
val context = LocalContext.current
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<YoutubeViewModel>()

if (viewModel.youtubePlayer.value == null) {
    val iFrameOptions = IFramePlayerOptions.Builder()
        .controls(1)
        .fullscreen(1)
        .build()

    viewModel.youtubePlayer.value =

        YouTubePlayerView(context).apply {
            enableAutomaticInitialization = false
            initialize(
                youTubePlayerListener =  object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener(){
                    override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(id,0f)
                    }
                },
                playerOptions = iFrameOptions
            )
            addFullscreenListener(
                fullscreenListener = object : FullscreenListener {
                    override fun onEnterFullscreen(
                        fullscreenView: View,
                        exitFullscreen: () -> Unit
                    ) {
                        viewModel.fullScreenView.value = fullscreenView
                    }

                    override fun onExitFullscreen() {
                        viewModel.fullScreenView.value = null
                    }
                }
            )
        }
}


viewModel.youtubePlayer.value?.let { player ->
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ){
        DisposableEffect(
            AndroidView(
                factory = {
                    player
                }
            ),
            effect = {
                onDispose {
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

viewModel.fullScreenView.value?.let{ fullScreenPlayer ->
    LockScreenOrientation(orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            fullScreenPlayer
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
} ?: LockScreenOrientation(orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)

}
```

But the issue is that when you change the orientation of the screen, it flickers the dialog. It shows the background screen first and then opens the dialog. How do I prevent this behavior?